# Jquery not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

First I echoed a button using PHP with `value='pause'`.Then I wrote a simple if statement in jquery

```
$(":button").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value") == "pause"){
             alert($(this).attr("value"));
             $(this).attr("value") = "play";
            }else{
                alert($(this).attr("value"));
             $(this).attr("value") = "pause";
            }
        });
```

But the result is always `alert("pause");`
What I am trying to do is if I click the button with `value='pause'`, i want to execute an ajax request and change its value to 'play' so that on the next click it will execute another bit of code and set its value back to pause.

Comment: `$(this).attr("value", "play") `; instead of `$(this).attr("value") = "play";`

Comment: `$(this).val("play")`

Comment: You shouldn't force jQuery to obey you, It should decide by itself if it obey you. #jQueryHasRightToo.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon i know iam missing something but iam not sure there is anything

Comment: Please rephrase you question title... As it is, it's not addressing to the problem and it is useless to others...

Answer (score 4):

This code is meaningless:

```
$(this).attr("value") = "pause";
```

That probably generated errors that you're not paying attention to. When working with JavaScript code, *always* have your console open.

What you want is:

```
$(this).attr("value", "pause");
```

Even better, as IFun points out:

```
$(this).val("pause");
```

Make sure to consult the [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) documentation.

Comment: `val()` would make more sense than `attr` (or `value()`) :)

Comment: Working code is even better than that, yeah! Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).value("pause");` not working, you have to use: `$(this).val("pause");`

Comment: @IFun Already corrected. Thanks for the note though.

Comment: yes,$(this).val() is returning a object

Comment: @Nisthar That's what `val()` does when called without arguments. If you call it with an argument, it assigns instead.

Comment: Yeah.Got it working.Thanks tadman,IFun.Wasted one day on this little problem